# How to further my Javascript development using cheap resources?

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

I've been studying JS in my free time for about a year now while maintaining a full time job not in the tech industry. Even though I'm still a slow minded fool, I think I've gained a fairly solid concept of the language and want to further my JS education and development.

The issue is that I live in an area with a smaller population density so a majority of my learning inherently has to be online or through books.

#### Finally to the point...

How does everyone keep up-to-date with development standards? What cheap resources or other platforms|websites|blogs|institutions exist that I can access to improve my Javascript skills and strengthen the illusion that I can become a competent web developer?

Comment: While this is a great question for discussion someplace, it's far too broad to be an on-topic question for Stack Overflow. I recommend reading over the help center to understand what questions are considered on-topic here, then looking for somewhere else to seek discussion on this subject.

Comment: The remaining problem is that the ominous "somewhere else" place simply does not adequately exist. If I'm wrong I'd be so glad to learn!

Answer (score 2):

> How does everyone keep up-to-date with development standards?

Reddit and javascript chatrooms.

> What cheap resources or other platforms|websites|blogs|institutions exist that I can access to improve my Javascript skills and strengthen the illusion that I can become a competent web developer?

Build your own website! github offers free hosting for websites, plus a repo is nice. Make something that will help you stand out from the sea of other up and coming junior web devs.

Comment: also while your there on github use the explore tab look at the trending packages, the showcases have a lot on javascript. Some of the stuff I use daily as a web developer. I still think the best thing to do is also get out there think something up and build up. Its the best way to learn you'll pull your hair out at times but it will be worth it I promise!

Answer (score 0):

There is a web site named [Packt Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/). This web site offers one free eBook a day. Many times that book will be on JavaScript. They also offer a low cost subscription which gives you access to many of their books and videos.